# in wordpress: link to js inside header works, line to js in functions.php don't

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this weird problem.

I have a link to js file in my header.php and I want to move them to the functions.php. Problem is that I get this error in the console when I do. (And something don't work)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sharrre'
```

So I use this link in the header.php now.

```
<script src="http://sharrre.com/js/jquery.sharrre-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
```

And I use this code to move it to the functions.php

```
// load the theme JS
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sharrre', 'http://sharrre.com/js/jquery.sharrre-1.3.4.min.js' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

What can the problem be?

Comment: Remove that line from `header.php`

Comment: If script is dependent on jQuery, make sure it gets load after jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

1. Be ABSOLUTELY sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file.
2. Be sure that you've included the script after you've included
   jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.
3. Rename your function name to something more unique. It could be
   causing a conflict with another call. Try naming it
   `sharrre_jquery_script()`